# Extend numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 2d numpy arrays like

```
array2D_1 = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
array2D_2 = np.arange(10,19).reshape(3,3)
```

Is it possible to append the second array to the first as just one column?

To concat two numpy arrays I have tryed the following function:

```
def _concat_two_features(self, array2D_1, array2D_2):
    return np.concatenate((array2D_1, array2D_2), axis=1)
```

and also

```
def _append_two_features(self, array2D_1, array2D_2):
        return np.append((array2D_1, array2D_2), axis=1)
```

Both result in the same array

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 3,  4,  5, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 6,  7,  8, 16, 17, 18]])
```

What I would like to have is:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2, [10, 11, 12]],
       [ 3,  4,  5, [13, 14, 15]],
       [ 6,  7,  8, [16, 17, 18]]])
```

I also tried something like this:

```
np.concatenate((array2D_1,[array2D_2]),axis=1)
```

But this doesn't the operation eather.

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 3 dimension(s)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: just curious... why do you want that?

Comment: With `axis`, np.append just does concatenate.  Look at its code

Comment: @some_name.py I have a multi dimensional feature which need to be considered as single value

Comment: @hpaulj what do you want to say? the output shows your answer already

Comment: What you seek is not a multidimensional numeric array.  `concatenate` can't do it.

Comment: @hpaulj the output needs to be (4,3). (3,3) + (1,3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

```
import numpy as np

array2D_1 = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
array2D_2 = np.arange(10,19).reshape(3,3)

out = np.empty(shape=(3,4),dtype=np.object)
out[:,:3] = array2D_1

out[:,3] = list(array2D_2)
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1, 2, array([10, 11, 12])],
       [3, 4, 5, array([13, 14, 15])],
       [6, 7, 8, array([16, 17, 18])]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: This is quiet perfect! Thx

Answer (score 1):

OK, there is a way to use `concatenate`, but you have to work with object dtype arrays.  This can't be done with numeric arrays.

```
In [6]: x=np.empty(array2D_2.shape[0],object); x[:]=list(array2D_2);
In [7]: x
Out[7]: 
array([array([10, 11, 12]), array([13, 14, 15]), array([16, 17, 18])],
      dtype=object)
In [8]: np.concatenate((array2D_1.astype(object), x[:,None]), axis=1)
Out[8]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, array([10, 11, 12])],
       [3, 4, 5, array([13, 14, 15])],
       [6, 7, 8, array([16, 17, 18])]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thx, great idea. However, I will accept the solution that was proposed preveously, since it is more readable